# VDI_CLIENT_OTHER wait type in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, alwayson

After direct seeding on an on-prem SQL Server 2016, I still have 8 sessions (8 CPUs) permanently waiting on the VDI_CLIENT_OTHER wait type, for two days. It seems to be the result of direct seeding, as mentioned in this anwser.

[Azure SQL high wait time on "VDI_CLIENT_OTHER"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579103/azure-sql-high-wait-time-on-vdi-client-other)

And Indeed direct seeding was completed two days ago.

I will kill the sessions I guess, as they just appear to do nothing. Does anyone has more info about the wait type, or had the same issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering if you did kill the sessions, and whether that caused any issues ?

Comment: The sessions resisted being killed, they stayed alive. They disappeared after a service restart, with no trouble. The direct seeding was marked completed, so these sessions had no real purpose.